# Null Parameter Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having a problem calling an Edit method in an application I am creating. In the view an ActionLink is clicked that should be passing the order number to the Edit method as a parameter and opening an edit page with the info for the order populated in the fields. However upon clicking the link I receive the error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'orderNum' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult Edit(Int32)' in 'AddressUpdater.WebUI.Controllers.OrderController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>       Parameter name: parameters

However the parameter is present in the URL. Here are the relevant method:

```
public ViewResult Edit(int orderNum)
{
    Order order = repository.Orders.First(o => o.OrderNumber == orderNum);
    return View(order);
}
```

If if change the parameter to `int? orderNum` the page will render without an error but none of the data is there.

Comment: How are you calling the url, and more importantly, how are you mapping the route?

Comment: ActionLink is posted below. Here si the route (it's the default):

`routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Order", 
                action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably there's something wrong with the sending of the data to the action method `Edit`, i.e. in your action link. Just open some devtool like Firebug or Chrome Dev tools to inspect what is being sent to the server.

When your url looks like

```
Edit?OrderNumber=1234
```

then you need to have a matching parameter on your Action method like

```
public ViewResult Edit(int orderNumber) {...}
```

Instead

```
Edit(int orderNum){...}
```

won't work. Basically url parameter name and action method parameter name have to match (not case sensitive, but the name has to match)

Comment: According to the "Net" tab in Firebug (I'm not sure if that's what I should be using) it is sending a `GET Edit?OrderNumber=10000002`. When using the debugger in VS10 it shows orderNum as being null. This is the link in the view that should be passing the order number to the method
`@Html.ActionLink(order.OrderNumber.ToString(), "Edit", new { order.OrderNumber })`

Comment: @ian See my updated post: you need to rename the parameter of your action method `orderNumber` instead of `orderNum`.

Comment: Wow. I feel foolish lol. thanks for the help and teaching me a valuable lesson in naming parameters.